# Vigenère cipher SECRET

Tags: decryption

Decrypt “jjjj aaa cccc ddddd” using Vigenère cipher with the key “CONVO”. I used 2 different generator and online calculator and i am getting 2 different results

Comment: There's a few subtleties in how one can define it, so getting different results from different tools is not surprising - setting aside other issues common to such tools, such as encoding. That said, have you considered doing it by hand, using the specific definitions of whatever course you are participating in?

Comment: Well, you are seemingly trying to learn cryptography. This is a good basic lesson: **don't trust online tools** unless they clearly specify how they compute things. This definitely also goes for tools "that do AES" and other modern algorithms.

Comment: I'd guess some implementations use A=0, others might use A=1. Your example needs A=0 to work.